# iPhone home page

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator

Let's say I have created one simple project and this would be my first page of the iPhone/iPad.  Is this possible? Could I control the next applications sitting in the same page only...?

Comment: edited for clarity, as much as was possible...

Comment: do not understand by control next applications

Comment: you can enter "wiggle mode" - but that's manual. Nothing else is possible to change the position of apps on the screens

Answer (score 1):

As best as I can understand the question: No.